# QtQuick setting up model in TableView

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtableview, qsqltablemodel

so I have a tableview on a qmlfile, I'm trying to set the model from  c++.

The model I'm using is QSqlTableModel, if a create a new tableview and set the model from c++ it seems to work, but when I pass the model to the model property in the qmlfile it doesn't work and I can't figure out why...

the c++ model code is:

```
QSqlTableModel * SqlEventModel::getTableData(QString tableName, QTableView *item){

    const QString queryStr = "SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE tbl_name = '" + tableName +"' AND type = 'table'" ;
    QSqlQuery query(queryStr);
    if (!query.exec())
        qFatal("Query failed");


    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database(":memory:");

    QSqlTableModel *model = new QSqlTableModel(item, db);
    model->setTable(tableName);
    model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
    model->select();


    int i=0;
    while (query.next()){
        model->setHeaderData(i, Qt::Vertical, query.value(i).toString());
        i++;
    }

   return   model;

}
```

that returns a model which works if within c++ I create a tableview and assign the model but when I do this:

```
TableView{
    id: table;
    width: parent.width -100
    height: parent.height -200
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.topMargin: 90
    model: SqlEventModel.getTableData(GData.tName,table)
}
```

it doesn't work, it just shows an empty table even though when I debug the tableview model is not empty...

if I add:

```
QTableView *view =  new QTableView();
view->setModel(model);
view->show();
```

just before the return on the c++ function I get a new window with a table which properly displays the table... I tried adding columns with the same rolename that I give in c++ and they won't populate either.... here's a screenshot of both tables

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which columns to display with `TableViewColumn`. This is documented in [`TableView`'s documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html#details):

```
TableView {
    TableViewColumn {
        role: "title"
        title: "Title"
        width: 100
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        role: "author"
        title: "Author"
        width: 200
    }
    model: libraryModel
}
```

Comment: doesn't work, and if I add these three lines in the  c++ code :    "       QTableView *view =  new QTableView();
   view->setModel(model);
   view->show(); " a new view with the table appears, but the one on the window I made on qml doesn't seem to work

Comment: You'll need to provide a complete example then.